# Neo4j Full text Index that includes properties from a 1-n node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j schema with a 1-n relation:

```
// a concept might have multiple accessions
(:Concept{name}) - [:hasAccession] -> (:Accession{code, source})
```

I'd like to create a 'nameOrAccession' full-text index (ie, to support both speed and Lucene syntax like "'Computer Science' OR 'CS00*'"), which should find nodes based on the `name` property or `Accession.code` property.

I know I could achieve this by creating two full-text indexes, one for `Concept.name` and the other for `Accession.code`, and then I could combine the two in a single `UNION` query.

But is it possible to simplify the query side by creating one index only? Ie, one that is about a 'top' (or 'central', or alike) node and would include properties from related nodes?

My understanding is it isn't possible, but I'd like to check if I'm missing something.

**EDIT**: I also know I could include multiple node labels in the same index (`CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ... FOR (n:Concept|Accession)...`), but that's not what I want, since this kind of index would find both concepts and accessions, while I want a query that finds concepts only, possibly based on their accession codes).

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single [fulltext index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes/semantic-indexes/full-text-indexes/#create-full-text-indexes) to cover the `name` and `code` properties of `Concept` and `Accession` nodes:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX nameAndCode FOR (n:Concept|Accession) ON EACH [n.name, n.code]
```

*Note: Aside from `:Concept.name` and `:Accession.code`, the index would also include `:Concept.code` and `:Accession.name` if they happen to exist. If they do, change their property names to avoid polluting the index.*

Once that index is defined, this query may work for your use case:

```
// $name and $code are parameters
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
  "nameAndCode",
  "'" + $name + "' OR '" + $code + "'") YIELD node, score
CALL {
  WITH node
  WITH node WHERE node.name = $name
  RETURN node AS concept

  UNION

  WITH node
  WITH node WHERE node.code = $code
  MATCH (concept)-[:hasAccession]->(node)
  RETURN concept
}
RETURN concept, score
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work for me. I'd like to find Concept instances only, based on their properties. I already knew your approach, but it finds Concept U Accession, and that's not what I want.

Comment: See my updated answer for a Cypher query that may work for your use case (as I understand it).

Comment: thanks @cybersam. That should work, although, if there isn't a better way, maybe two indexes (one for concept's name and one for accession) and one UNION query with two calls to db.index.fulltext.queryNodes() would be simpler (I'm crafting the queries from Java code). I'll try both and add some feedback here on SO.

Comment: Also, I don't expect to search like '$name' OR '$code', the user will give me $token and this will be either a code or an accession, ie, your index would get the $token param only.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, you can have two indexes, however it will be a nightmare in the long term, `OR` queries will be fine, `AND` queries will just be non performant, combining FullTextSearch with `AND` on two indexes along with an optional pattern in Cypher will lead to very, very long and hard hours of pain.

There is no single answer tho, it will depend on the level of performance you need, the level of changes you can do at ingestion level or the level of pain you want to have.

- @cybersam answer is a valid one
- you can create new nodes representing the pairs of texts between concept and ascensions and have an index on that and automate this process during ingestion and vice versa
- you can use [CDC](https://neo4j.com/docs/cdc/current/) to automate all this process in the background

Comment: thanks. I can't see the difficulties you mention. My idea is: create conceptNameIdx, accessionCodeIdx, and then, when querying by token: queryNodes ( conceptNameIdx, $token ) UNION { queryNodes ( accessionCodeIdx, $token ) YIELD node AS accession MATCH (c:Concept) - [:hasAccession] -> (accession) RETURN c }